# Attempting JavaScript Snake Game - Snake Tail is getting drawn in pieces; not together

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to figure out why the tail array of my snake is only getting drawn one block at a time when I eat the food. I want it to get drawn all together and follow the snake head(to make a complete snake). Only **one** rectangle gets drawn over the spot the food used to be when my snake head runs over the food; and the head just keeps getting drawn wherever I move to.

It's as if the tail array of the snake is getting drawn all around the map, and not actually getting drawn 'connected'.

Below is my code.

Thank you for any help!

Entire Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        .new-div {
          display:flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          width:400px;
          height:400px;
          position:absolute;
          top:0;
          z-index:4000;
        }

        .game-content {
          position:relative;
          top:35px;
          right:0px;
          border:none;
          border-radius:5px;
          padding:10px;
          background-color:teal;
          color:white;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      window.onload = function() {
        fruit.generateNewFruit();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
      }

      var tools = {
        canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
        drawRect: function(x, y, sizeX, sizeY, color, type, stroke, strokeColor) {
          if (type == 'fill') {
            this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
            this.ctx.fillRect(x, y, sizeX, sizeY);
            if (stroke == true) {
              this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
              this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, sizeX, sizeY);
            }
          } else {
            this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
            this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, sizeX, sizeY);
          }
        },
        writeText: function(text, x, y, font, fontStyle, color) {
          if (font) {
            this.ctx.font = fontStyle;
          }
          this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
          this.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        }
      }

      let game = {
        x: tools.canvas.width / 2 - 40,
        y: tools.canvas.height / 2,
        gameOver: false,
        gameOverMsg: function(msg, font) {
          let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
          let button = document.createElement('button');
          let btnText = document.createTextNode('Play Again');

          button.className = "game-content";
          newDiv.className = "new-div";

          tools.writeText(msg, this.x, this.y, true, "16px bold sans-serif", "#fff");

          button.appendChild(btnText);
          newDiv.appendChild(button);
          document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

          document.getElementsByClassName('game-content')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
            game.gameOver = true;
          });
        }
      }

      let map = {
        tileX: 0,
        tileY: 0,
        tileRow: 20,
        tileCol: 20,
        tileSize: 20,
        tileColor: 'gray',
        drawMap: function() {
          for (let col = 0; col < this.tileCol; col++) {
            for (let row = 0; row < this.tileRow; row++) {
              tools.drawRect(this.tileX, this.tileY, this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileColor, 'fill');
              this.tileX += this.tileSize;
            }
            this.tileX = 0;
            this.tileY += this.tileSize;
          }
          this.tileY = 0;
        },
        outOfBounds: function() {
          if (snake.x < 0 || snake.x > tools.canvas.width || snake.y < 0 || snake.y > tools.canvas.height) {
            game.gameOver = true;
          }
        }
      }

      let fruit = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        size: 20,
        fillColor: 'hotpink',
        strokeColor: 'black',
        drawFruit: function() {
          tools.drawRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size, this.fillColor, 'fill', true, this.strokeColor);
        },
        generateNewFruit: function() {
          this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 20;
          this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 20;
        }
      }

      let snake = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        size: 20,
        color: 'black',
        direction: '',
        bodySize: 0,
        init: false,
        tail: [],
        drawSnake: function() {

          for (let i=0; i < this.bodySize; i++) {
            tools.drawRect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, this.size, this.size, this.color, 'fill', true, 'lime');
          }

          tools.drawRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size, this.color, 'fill', true, 'lime');
        },
        move: function() {
          if (this.direction == 'left') {
            this.x-=this.size;
          }
          else if (this.direction == 'up') {
            this.y-=this.size;
          }
          else if (this.direction == 'right') {
            this.x+=this.size;
          }
          else if (this.direction == 'down') {
            this.y+=this.size;
          }
        }
      }

      let drawEverything = function() {
          if (game.gameOver) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(main);
          }



          if (snake.x === fruit.x && snake.y === fruit.y) {
            fruit.generateNewFruit();
            snake.bodySize++;


          if (snake.bodySize === snake.tail.length) {
            for (let i=0; i < snake.tail.length - 1; i++) {
              snake.tail[i] = snake.tail[i+1];
            }
          }

          snake.tail[snake.bodySize-1] = {x: snake.x, y: snake.y};

          }

          tools.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tools.canvas.width, tools.canvas.height);
          map.drawMap();
          map.outOfBounds();
          snake.drawSnake();
          snake.move();
          fruit.drawFruit();
      }



      let main = function() {
          if (game.gameOver) {
            game.gameOverMsg("Game Over");
            cancelAnimationFrame(main);
            return;
          } else {
            drawEverything();

            setTimeout(function() {
              requestAnimationFrame(main);
            }, 1000/20);
          }
      }

      window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        let key = e.keyCode;

        switch(key) {
          case 65: snake.direction = 'left';
          break;
          case 87: snake.direction = 'up';
          break;
          case 68: snake.direction = 'right';
          break;
          case 83: snake.direction = 'down';
          break;
        }
      });

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is where I shift the snake down

```
  let drawEverything = function() {
          if (game.gameOver) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(main);
          }



          if (snake.x === fruit.x && snake.y === fruit.y) {
            fruit.generateNewFruit();
            snake.bodySize++;


          if (snake.bodySize === snake.tail.length) {
            for (let i=0; i < snake.tail.length - 1; i++) {
              snake.tail[i] = snake.tail[i+1];
            }
          }

          snake.tail[snake.bodySize-1] = {x: snake.x, y: snake.y};

          }

          tools.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tools.canvas.width, tools.canvas.height);
          map.drawMap();
          map.outOfBounds();
          snake.drawSnake();
          snake.move();
          fruit.drawFruit();
      }
```

This where I draw the updated-shifted-down tail and snake head

```
drawSnake: function() {

          for (let i=0; i < this.bodySize; i++) {
            tools.drawRect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, this.size, this.size, this.color, 'fill', true, 'lime');
          }

          tools.drawRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size, this.color, 'fill', true, 'lime');
}
```

I don't know if it's a problem with my drawSnake function or not; but for whatever reason, it's not wanting to draw the tail array all together as one set of blocks.

Comment: You don't seem to be updating the tail positions as part of your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put the for loop outside of the if statement for food eaten.